Derivation of cellular boundary formula
I was working through Hatcher's derivation of the cellular boundary formula and was trying to fill in all the nitty gritty details. One I thing I could not understand is how to choose the appropriate generators and maps such that the cellular boundary formula works.
I defined the following:

let $\rho_n$ be the most geometrically obvious homeomorphism of a standard $n$-simplex $\Delta^n$ into $n$-disk $D^n$ (by that I mean, we basically inscribe $\Delta^n$ into $D^n$ and the expand it onto the disk: I can write down the exact formulas if need be). Then we can take the singular simplex $\rho_n$ as the generator $[D^n]$ of $H_n (D^n, S^{n - 1})$.

let $[S^{n - 1}] = \partial [D^n]$ be the generator of $\widetilde{H}_{n - 1} (S^{n - 1})$.

let $$q_n: (D^n, S^{n - 1}) \to (S^n, pt),\quad q(\vec{x}) = \left(2 \sqrt{1 - \|\vec{x}\|^2} \cdot \vec{x}, 1 - 2\|\vec{x}\|^2\right)$$ be a quotient map that takes the boundary of a disk $D^n$ into the south pole of a sphere $S^n$.


Obviously, the induced map $${q_n}_*: H_n (D^n, S^{n - 1}) \to \widetilde{H}_n(S^n)$$ is an isomorphism. But does it send a generator $[D^n]$ to the generator $[S^n]$. If yes, why? If not, how do we choose a map $q_n$ and a generator $[D^n]$ so that this is true?
I know there are many posts on this site regarding this exact topic, but there hasn't been one that would completely clear my confusion. Thanks for all the help!
Edit: To elaborate on the connection between my post and cellular homology: Hatcher defines the generators $[e_\alpha ^n] \in H_n (X^n, X^{n - 1})$ as $(\Phi_\alpha)_* [D^n]$, where $\Phi_\alpha$ is the characteristic map of the cell $e_\alpha ^n$. Now taking a look at his diagram on page 141, the cellular boundary formula ONLY makes sense if the composition
$$H_{n - 1} (X^{n - 1}, X^{n - 2}) \xrightarrow{\cong} \widetilde{H}_{n- 1} (X^{n - 1} / X^{n - 2}) \xrightarrow{(q_\beta)_*} \widetilde{H}_{n-1} (S^{n -1} _\beta)$$ maps $[e_\beta]$ into $[S^{n - 1} _\beta]$. But this is not a given (from what I can understand), and depends on the choice of the map $q_\beta$. So I'd like to explicitly define some $q_\beta: X^{n - 1} / X^{n - 2} \to S^{n - 1}$ for which the cellular boundary formula DOES make sense. So I came to the idea to define $q_\beta$ such that the composition
$$D_\beta ^{n - 1} \xrightarrow{\Phi_\alpha} X^{n - 1} \to X^{n - 1} / X^{n - 2} \xrightarrow{q_\beta} S_\beta ^{n - 1}$$ is equal to $q_{n - 1}: (D^{n - 1}, S^{n - 2}) \to (S^{n - 1}, pt)$ (as above). So then if ${q_{n - 1}}_* [D^{n - 1}] = [S^{n - 1} _\beta]$, then $[e_\beta ^{n - 1}]$ gets mapped to $[S^{n - 1} _\beta]$.

Isn't it immediate since both groups are free on one generator?

Well it could also map $[D^n]$ into $-[S^n]$. Thats what I'm trying to figure out.

You should precisely explain the relation of your question to Hatcher's diagram on p. 141.

@PaulFrost Ok I'll edit the question, give me a couple minutes.

I'm writing this answer mostly to gather my own thoughts. I'm not 100% sure this is correct, but I thought it might help other people who are confused by the derivation of cellular boundary formula.
With regards to my first question
I still have no idea whether ${q_n}_*$ maps $[D^n]$ into $[S^n]$ or $-[S^n]$. I could not find the answer anywhere. Whenever you derive the cellular boundary formula, this question is always there in some way - and every author basically avoids this question in their own way. Ultimately though, it doesn't make a difference when you're actually computing the cellular homology.
So how to make sense of the cellular boundary formula?
Once and for all, we prescribe the orientation $[D^n]$ of $H_n (D^n, S^{n - 1})$ for each $n$, which induces the orientation $[S^{n - 1}] = \partial [D^n]$ of $\widetilde{H}_{n-1} (S^{n - 1})$. We also prescribe a fixed quotient map $$q_n: (D^n, S^{n - 1}) \to (S^n, pt)$$ for each $n$. Then for each cell $e_\beta ^{n - 1}$, we define a map $q_\beta: X^{n - 1} / X^{n - 2} \to S^{n - 1}$ such that the composition $$D_\beta ^{n - 1} \xrightarrow{\Phi_\beta} X^{n - 1} \to X^{n - 1} / X^{n - 2} \xrightarrow{q_\beta} S_\beta ^{n - 1}$$ is equal to $q_{n - 1}$ (we can always compose $q_\beta$ with a self-homeomorphism of $S^{n - 1}$ to achieve this). Now we have two possibilities.

${q_{n - 1}}_* [D^{n - 1}] = [S^{n - 1}]$: In this case, the map $d_n$ as defined by Hatcher really does map $[e_\alpha ^n]$ into $\sum_\beta (\deg \Delta_{\alpha \beta}) \cdot [e_\beta ^{n - 1}].$

${q_{n - 1}}_* [D^{n - 1}] = - [S^{n - 1}]$: In this case, $d_n$ maps $[e_\alpha ^n]$ into $- \sum_\beta (\deg \Delta_{\alpha \beta}) \cdot [e_\beta ^{n - 1}].$


But notice that both of the maps described above have the same image and the same kernel (by linearity). Therefore, the plus/minus sign in the map $d_n$ will not affect any of the homology groups. So when we calculate the homology of some CW complex $X$, we define for each $n$ a map $$d_n': H_n (X^n, X^{n - 1}) \to H_{n - 1} (X^{n - 1}, X^{n - 2}),\quad [e_\alpha ^n]\mapsto \sum_\beta (\deg \Delta_{\alpha \beta}) \cdot [e_\beta ^{n - 1}].$$ Notice that $d_n'$ is not necessarily equal to $d_n$ (I think this is what bugged me while reading Hatcher), but is instead $d_n ' = \pm d_n$. As a result, $d_n ' \circ d_{n-1} ' = 0$ and we have a chain complex $$\cdots \to H_{n + 1} (X^{n + 1}, X^n) \xrightarrow{d_{n + 1}'} H_n (X^n, X^{n - 1}) \xrightarrow{d_n '} H_{n - 1} (X^{n - 1}, X^{n - 2}) \to \cdots$$ with homology groups
$$\frac{\ker d_n '}{ \mathrm{im}\, d_{n + 1} '} = \frac{\ker d_n }{ \mathrm{im}\, d_{n + 1} } = H_n ^{CW} (X) \cong H_n (X).$$
How do some other authors avoid this question?
What Bredon does in his book is he basically redefines the degree of $${\Delta_{\alpha \beta}}_*: \widetilde{H}_{n - 1} (S^{n-1}) \to \widetilde{H}_{n - 1} (S^{n-1})$$ by taking $[S^{n - 1}]$ as the generator of the group on the left and ${q_{n - 1}}_* [D^{n - 1}]$ as the generator of the group on the right. Then the cellular boundary formula does in fact hold for $d_n$.
But for example in May's Concise course in algebraic topology, he basically does the opposite. He defines $d_n'$ similarly as above, then shows these maps form a chain complex whose homology groups are isomorphic to the singular homology groups and thereby avoids this issue altogether.
